# An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file. Tool agent requires sharing to be disabled

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, datadog

I am trying to enable to datadog tracing for lambda function. I have followed the steps mentioned here https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/java/?tab=maven. After adding the layer and the environment variable I am getting below error. Can anyone please suggest how to fix this....

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:"/opt/java/lib/dd-java-agent.jar"
An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file.
Tool agent requires sharing to be disabled.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to use shared archive

Answer (score 0):

try changing the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:"/opt/java/lib/dd-java-agent.jar"` env var to `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:"/opt/java/lib/dd-java-agent.jar" -Xshare:"off"` and see if that helps.